# How to copy a single line from notepad by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, import, notepad

I Want to copy an specific line from a txt file (let's say the first line), so i could use that line in my program later. also i want to be able to copy other lines too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list does this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

readline() function should help you. It returns a list of lines which you could then use whenever you want in code.

Comment: hey. but how does this works? like if i want to copy the second line of my txt file i should write file.readline(2) ?

Comment: Try this(replace the path with your file path), `with open ("C:\Users\PycharmProjects\untitled\sorted_cron.txt", 'r') as f:`
`line=f.readlines()`
`print (line[0])`